# Using AES_ENCRYPT in another mode

Tags: mysql, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

Is it possible to use MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT functions in a mode other than ECB (like CBC)? Various questions on Stack Overflow talk about how MySQL uses ECB mode and to not use these functions. Am I better off doing the encryption/decryption in the programming language I'm working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 4/28/14:

It looks like MySQL 5.7.4 supports larger key sizes and different modes of operation. This was also backported to 5.6.17. Key sizes can now be 128, 192, or 256. Modes can be ECB, CBC, CFB1, CFB8, CFB128, or OFB if the underlying library is OpenSSL. yaSSL only allows ECB or CBC.

See here http://mysqlserverteam.com/understand-and-satisfy-your-aes-encryption-needs-with-5-6-17/

here http://mysqlserverteam.com/the-mysql-5-7-4-milestone-release-is-available/

here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_block_encryption_mode

and here https://twitter.com/morgo/statuses/459820794731065344 (morgo is a MySQL community manager at Oracle)

Answer (score 4):

No,  and that would be problematic for SQL Lookups.  ECB mode is useful for databases because it doesn't have an IV,  and there for there is a 1:1 ciphertext:plaintext relationship.

`select * from users where secret=aes_encrypt("some secret")`

If you used an IV in CBC mode you would have to iterate over every record.   This is why ECB mode was chosen.  Despite popular opinion ECB mode isn't always a problem,  and CBC mode can often introduce the possibility of a CBC-R attack using a decryption oracle.

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL 5.6 you can even set session encryption:

```
SET @@session.block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
```

You can then update a column as encrypted:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = AES_ENCRYPT(MSISDN, 'password', 'encryptionkey');
```

To decrypt:

```
SELECT CAST(aes_decrypt(COLUMN,'password','encryptionkey') AS CHAR) AS 'Encrypted COLUMN' FROM TABLE
```

Remember for this encryption, your key must have 16 characters.